# Prevent Alpha Color Pen from Overlapping?

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

I have a simple *highlighter* using a `Pen` object. When the size is very large, it creates odd stripes which you can fix by defining its Start & End Cap with`System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LineCap.Round` but it instantly overlaps itself and loses its transparency. A flat cap also loses its transparency when you draw over itself multiple times.

How can I create an opaque pen that does not overlap itself or create stripes with a large pen width?

```
private static Color baseColor = Color.Yellow;
bool Draw;
Graphics g;
Point start;
Point end;

     private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        g = this.CreateGraphics();
        Pen1.Color = Color.FromArgb(128, baseColor);
        Pen1.Width = 50;
        Pen1.StartCap = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LineCap.Flat; //I know it's default, just for clarification's sake
        Pen1.EndCap = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LineCap.Flat;   //' '''' '' ' '''''''  '''' ''' ''''''''''''' ' ''''
    }

     private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Draw = true;
        start = e.Location;
    }

     private void Form1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Draw = false;
    }

    private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Draw == true)
        {
            end = e.Location;
            g.DrawLine(Pen1, start, end);
            start = end;
        }
    }
```

It behaves like this; [image: Highlighter Example]

**Note:** Yes, I am aware `.CreateGraphics` is not a good drawing method, it has a unique purpose that is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: Do not draw the lines separately!! Collect them and use DrawLines (pl!) instead!! You may run into problems doing this because you don't draw correctly in the Paint event. See, it is usually NOT irrelevant to avoid basic mistakes ,-)  - Also look into the  pen.MiterLimit and try to keep it around half of the width of the pen!

Comment: Do you have an example snippet? I've converted it into DrawLines by doing this `Point[] pts = new Point[2] { start, end};` `g.DrawLines(Pen1, pts);` and I set the `MiterLimit = 50;` I still get the same results.

Comment: Yes, you need to collect __all__ your points, not just the two that make uip one line! The miterlimit will only come into play after you get the first problem out of the way..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two issues with the drawing objects:

- You draw each Line separately; this will create ugly artifacts where the common points overlap. Instead draw the lines all in one go with the `DrawLines` method! (Note the plural!)
- You did not restrict the `Pen.MiterLimit`; this creates ugly spikes when the lines directions change sharply. Try to restrict it to around 1/2 of the `Pen.Width` or less . Setting `LineJoin` is also recommened as well a the two `Caps`..

**Collect** the points of your current line in a `List<Point> currentPoints` in the `MouseMove` and collect upon `MouseUp` the `currentList` into a `List<List<Point>> allPointLists` !

then you can draw both in the `Paint` event..

```
    foreach (List<Point> points in allPointLists)
        if (points.Count > 1) e.Graphics.DrawLines(Pens.Gold, points.ToArray());
    if (currentPoints.Count > 1) e.Graphics.DrawLines(Pens.Gold, currentPoints.ToArray());
```

**Note** that it will pay immediately to do it right, i.e. draw **only** with a valid graphics object and **always** rely on the `Paint` event to make sure that the drawing is always updated as needed! Using `control.CreateGraphics` is almost always wrong and will hurt as soon as you go beyond a single non-persistent drawing operation..

[image]

Here is the full code:

```
List<Point> currentPoints = new List<Point>();
List<List<Point>> allPointLists = new List<List<Point>>();


private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    currentPoints = new List<Point>();
}

private void Form1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (currentPoints.Count > 1)
    {
        allPointLists.Add(currentPoints.ToList());
        currentPoints.Clear();
    }
}

private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        currentPoints.Add(e.Location);
        Invalidate();
    }
}
```

Here is the `Paint` event; note that I use two different `Pens` for the currently drawn lines and the older ones. Also note that you can use `DrawCurve` instead of `DrawLines` to get even smoother results..

Also note that I use a `List<T>` to be flexible wrt the number of elements and that I convert it to an array in the `Draw` commands..

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Color c1 = Color.FromArgb(66, 77, 88, 222);
    using (Pen pen = new Pen(c1, 50f))
    {
        pen.MiterLimit = pen.MiterLimit / 12;
        pen.LineJoin = LineJoin.Round;
        pen.StartCap = LineCap.Round;
        pen.EndCap = LineCap.Round;
        foreach (List<Point> points in allPointLists)
            if (points.Count > 1) e.Graphics.DrawLines(pen, points.ToArray());
    }
    Color c2 = Color.FromArgb(66, 33, 111, 222);

    using (Pen pen = new Pen(c2, 50f))
    {
        pen.MiterLimit = pen.MiterLimit / 4;
        pen.LineJoin = LineJoin.Round;
        pen.StartCap = LineCap.Round;
        pen.EndCap = LineCap.Round;
        if (currentPoints.Count > 1) e.Graphics.DrawLines(pen, currentPoints.ToArray());
    }
}
```

To prevent flicker don't forget to turn on `DoubleBuffered` for your `Form`; or use a `DoubleBuffered Panel` subclass or simply a `PictureBox`!

Final note: I left out the case of simple clicks; if they are supposed to paint you will have to catch them, probably best in the `if (points.Count > 1)` check and best do a `FillEllipse` at the right spot and with the right size..

**Update**

`List<T>` is so useful I hardly ever use `arrays` theses days. Here is how to make use of it to implement a `Clear` and an `Undo` button:

```
private void buttonClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    allPointLists.Clear();
    Invalidate();
}

private void buttonUndo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    allPointLists.Remove(allPointLists.Last());
    Invalidate();
}
```

Note two small corrections in the `MouseUp` code this has required to handle the `currentPoints` list properly! The clearing is obvious; the `ToList()` call is making a **copy** of the data, so we don't clear the instance we have just added to te List of Lists!

Comment: Is it not possible to create the same effect using a Bitmap persistent graphics method instead of OnPaint? I get the same results using other methods but when I use OnPaint it works. Otherwise, this is an excellent method.

Comment: Of course you can paint into a Bitmap, if a) you have a Bitmap and b) you are sure of the graphics. You would use only a currentPoints list and upon MouseUp draw it into the Bitmap. But your question was ll about drawing onto a Form!? To paint into a Bitmap you use ` Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);` and the same methods as above.. Note that your original code is __non-persistent__ !!

Comment: In the answer? Simply do a `currentPoints.Clear(); allPointLists.Clear(); Invalidate();` Similarily you can implement an unlimited `undo` by removing the last element from `allPointLists` . Do have a look into `List<T>`, it is so useful !!  I have updated the answer.

Comment: Ah, much clearer, thank you so much. You may also want to add `currentPoints.Clear();` onto the clear button in the answer. The ability to undo is absolutely stellar. Lists actually do seem more powerful than arrays.

Comment: Yes, and that is just the beginning: They also are a) generic, so a List<Point> is type safe (as opposed to an ArrayList) and they work very well with LINQ. ((Btw; the edit you suggested was observant but not necessary, as the change in the mouseup already takes care of clearing the currentpoints list))