# Why do I see this jagged curves?

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, curve

I have a canvas and draw curve with this code:

```
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(canvas.BackgroundImage))
{
    g.DrawCurve(pen, points);
```

`points` is array that I fill that by mouse location points. 
In the result I see some jagged lines that I didn't draw.

You can see them here(in red rectangles):

[image]

What can i do about this?

Comment: Simply set `MiterLimit` and `LineJoins` for your `Pen'`! See [here for an example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36046538/prevent-alpha-color-pen-from-overlapping/36047319#36047319)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you is see is the somewhat unlucky combination of the **default** for [`Linejoin`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.pen.linejoin%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which is `Miter` and the **default** for [`MiterLimit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.pen.miterlimit%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which is 10.

Instead you have a choice of either picking one of the other `LineJoin` options or reducing the `MiterLimit` to say less than half the `Pen.Width`..

```
using (Pen myPen = new Pen(Color.Blue, 24f))
{
    // either another LineJoine;
    myPen.LineJoin = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LineJoin.Round;
    // or a reduced MiterLimit:
    myPen.MiterLimit = 1+ myPen.Width / 5f;
}
```